# About the irrationality measure of $\pi$

Tags: number-theory

Let us denote the irrationality measure of a real number $\alpha$ by $\mu(\alpha)$. It can be quite easily deduced from Dirichlet's approximation theorem that $\mu(\alpha)\ge 2$ for every irrational $\alpha$ and already Liouville showed that $\mu(\alpha)\le n$ for every algebraic number $\alpha$ of degree $n$. The proof of this is elementary and short. The very deep Thue-Siegel-Roth theorem even states  $\mu(\alpha)\le 2$ for every algebraic number $\alpha$ independent of its degree, so we have $\mu(\alpha)= 2$ for every irrational algebraic number $\alpha$. As $\pi$ is irrational $\mu(\pi)\ge 2$ surely holds and it has been proved by Mahler that $\pi$ is not a Liouville number, i.e. $\mu(\pi)\lt \infty$. The sharpest upper bound I know of is 7.103205334137... What I would like to know now is whether this has meanwhile been reduced to $2$, i.e. is it known that $\mu(\pi)= 2$ or has $\mu(\pi)\gt 2$ been proved?

Comment: If we knew that the value is exactly $2$ , this upper bound would be given. I doubt that it has been proven that the measure is larger than $2$. So , I guess every value between $2$ (inclusive) and the upper bound is possible.

Comment: What @Peter said. I'd add that it is widely believed that the right number is $2$, mainly because that's the right number for almost all reals.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson In which precise sense is "almost" to be interpreted here and how can this statement  then be shown or at least been made plausible?

Comment: All but a set of measure zero. There's a statement at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation,_metric_theory_of and a proof at Theorem 198 in Hardy & Wright, 6th edition. Or, search for "Khinchine's theorem on diophantine approximation."